# Django-postman get message list

Tags: python, django

I've installed and configured `django-postman` based on this [documentation](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Everything is ok. Now I want to get a message list(list of unread and undeleted messages) of authenticated users in a template, but that sounds like this is just an inbox view that shows it completely (with inbox, trash, sent, received messages) while I just need a message list. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What do you want exactly? You're saying you need a message list, but instead you get a message list.. You mean you don't want to see sub-folders?

Comment: yes,I don't need trash,sent and other parts,instead I want to get a message list like the way I get number of unread messages.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution:

in `views.py` :

```
unread_messages=request.user.received_messages.filter(read_at__isnull=True,sender_deleted_at__isnull=True)
```

in `template` :

```
{% for m in unread_messages %}
   <!--do stuff-->
{% endfor %}
```